VBA String Assignment mistaken for Library Declaration
My xlsm file worked just fine until I moved it to an external hard drive and factory reset my computer. The issue is when a value from a prefilled combobox is assigned to a variable. After moving my file, it appears to be looking for a library with the variable's name instead of assigning a value.
What is causing this?
See code and images below.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    SearchByCb.List = Array("ZipCode", "City", "Last Tuned")
    NumNamesCb.List = Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
    ContactMthdCb.List = Array("Text", "Call")

'Start With ComboBox Initialized
Dim d As Object
Dim c As Range, k
Dim tmp As String
    
'This is where the error is thrown
'for some reason it is looking for a "SearchBy" library
SearchBy = SearchByCb.Value

Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each c In Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns("City").DataBodyRange
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
        d(c.Value) = d(c.Value) + 1
    End If
Next c

ReDim ComboBoxArr(d.Count - 1)
ReDim SortArr(d.Count - 1)

For Each k In d.Keys
    i = i + 1
    ComboBoxArr(i - 1) = k
Next k

SortArr() = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort(ComboBoxArr(), , , True)

SearchForCb.List = SortArr()

End Sub




I commented out the proposed problem and the error is still there. I also commended out highlighted line you said was not the issue, and then it worked fine. This shows the highlighted line is indeed the problem.

Something else I tried was declaring SearchBy... '''Dim SearchBy as String'''. This solved the issue but the same issue is occuring with other variables throughout my entire project. In my experience and from what I understand, VBA has not historically required declaration of strings, nor has it tried to find a library when a variabale is assigned a string value. It is also affecting redeclaration of arrays which is forcing me into an uncomfortable position. Why did it start doing this after I moved the file?

The answer was a missing library. I had to find it online and download it. Selenium Type Library to be specific.
